# Transition probabilities with drift-diffusion SDE with compound poisson process

Tags: probability

I am looking to find a transition kernel in the following control scenario:

Let $X_t = \mu \int\limits_0^t X_t \,dt + \sigma \int\limits_0^t X_t \,dB_t + Y_t$, where $X_t$ is some state process taking values in $\mathbb{R}_+$, $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}_+$. $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and $Y_t$ is a compound Poisson process given by
$$
 Y_t = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N_t} Z_i, \quad Z_i \sim \nu(a_\tau), \tau \le t.
$$
Here $N_t$ is a poisson process with constant intensity, and $Z_i$ is an $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted random variable whose distribution $\nu(\cdot)$ is dependent on a control action given by some agent at time $\tau \le t$, with $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(B_s, Y_s : 0 \le s \le t).$

I'm currently stuck trying to find the following: given some $x \subset \mathbb{R}_+$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and complete knowledge of the system up to time $t$, find 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_{t+h} \in x \mid X_t, a_{\tau})
\end{align}
Any starting advice or approaches would be greatly appreciated!